WY update manager - .NET Core migration
I searched but couldn't find anything to help - we currently have an application that has fixes/upgrades managed and released to clients using WY Updater.
We have recently upgraded our application from .NET 4.5.2 (I think, it's around there somewhere) to .NET 8.0 - a process that works on our local machine, but fails on our test server due to the runtime for .NET 8.0 not being available.
I'm looking for one of a few different solutions here - either a way to push the runtime alongside the update, or a way to replace WY entirely.
I've considered potentially running an intermediary upgrade that only serves to set up / install the .NET 8.0 runtime - but this may have issues with permissions, requiring elevated permissions.
Another option is to move to the self-contained .NET 8.0 version, but as the application still uses forms, we cannot do this until we find an alternative solution for UI.

You may want to tag your question with the wyupdate tag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wyupdate). If you spell it with a space, you won't find anything about WY Update or WY Updater, if the spell it with no space, there seems to be a bit of community
